# How to use Get and Filter in set to get values related to a particular user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

Im trying to get values of an order which a particular user made, I mean I have an e commerce app where a user can made purchases, I successfully got the order item to display when a user wants to make an order, but i want to get all the orders which are already purchased by that user to display in a different page (Order History), Im trying to use queryset for the Serializers but its just not work despite severally tweaks, and i have ready the docs but cant seem to get it right. Please help,

Model:

```
 user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(eOrderItem)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   payment = models.ForeignKey(
        'Payment', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    coupon = models.ForeignKey(
        'Coupon', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    being_delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    received = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    refund_requested = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    refund_granted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    qr_code = models.ImageField(upload_to='qrcode', blank=True)
```

This is the serializer for the (Order History)

```
class TicketSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order_items = serializers.SerializerMethodField()


    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_order_items(self, obj):
        return OrderItemSerializer().data
```

View:

```
class TicketDetailView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = TicketSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_object(self):
        try:
            # order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user).filter(ordered=True)
            # order = Order.objects.filter(order=True)
            # order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=True)
            order = Order.objects.filter(ordered=False, user=self.request.user)

            return order
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
           return Response({"message": "You do not have any ticket"}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

from the view, you can see i try tried may options with queryset, but its not work, It works when i use get(user=self.request.user), but when i pass `Order=True`(for order history) it says `get() returned more than one Order -- it returned 3!` and i understand because i use get() (other options dont work) when i pass `Order=False` (as it works for the order item to be purchased) it works because its just one at a time.

What do i do please, i just want to be about to get all the items that are order by a particular user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You expect multiples results that's why you should override `get_queryset()` and not `get_object()` (should be used for detail views):

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Order.objects.filter(ordered=False, user=self.request.user)
```